# How to use 2D array to display an image in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt and C++ in general. I have a 2d array of data (could be 64bit double). I would like to use this data to create an image to display in QT. I would be grateful if somebody could point me in the right direction or give me a example.

Comment: What kind of image should it be? Please provide more details on the problem.

Comment: @vahancho one double per pixel. It is not RGB. The data is like a grayscale image, and the value of each pixel is represented by a double type. For example, if the first pixel value is 198.88, then the double value is 198.88

Comment: Hm, but it should be some mapping between a double value to the corresponding RGB value. Otherwise how color of a pixel can be represented as a double value?

Comment: @vahancho emmm, yes. I will do some conversion for a double value to unsigned int value. Thanks for your help!